# How to integrate the nth root of n

Tags: integration

I am working on a problem in which there is an integral containing $x^\frac1x$. I have looked at this question for some help: [Behavior of the Nth root of N?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443626/behavior-of-the-nth-root-of-n)

I have changed $x^\frac1x$ to $e^{ln(x)/x}$ but I still have not found a way to integrate it. How can I integrate either equation? **Thanks.** *If you vote down, please tell me why so I can improve this question.*

Comment: Wolfram alpha say "no result found in terms of standard mathematical functions", so there is probably no easy way to do this. What's your problem exactly, is your integral definite or indefinite?

Comment: @Tryss The integral is definite(but inside a limit). I have already tried many of the online function integrators out there and none have given me an answer.

Comment: You may have more luck in posting the whole expression to calculate. Maybe only an asymptotic growth or an approximation is necessary for your problem

Comment: As said, it would be better to know what is the integral. Please, post it.

Comment: $\int x^{1/x}\,dx$ is not an elementary function.  Some (indeed most) integrals are like that.

Comment: @GEdgar Shouldn't it be (x^((1 / x) + 1))/((1 / x) + 1)?

Comment: @Progo: Only if the bottom $x$ is the variable, and the top $x$ is constant.

Comment: @GEdgar Then is can this function not be integrated? Doesn't every function have an anti-derivitive?

Comment: @GEdgar I basing that guess off of this: [https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100201165158AAlAqJy](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100201165158AAlAqJy)

Comment: It has an antiderivative, as does every continuous function.  But (as I said) this antiderivatvie is not an elementary function.

Comment: In that yahoo answer, the $n$ in the exponent is constant.  So then we can easily do the integral!

Comment: @GEdgar Do you have any suggestions for where I might start looking for the anti-derivitive of this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define
$$
F(x) = \int_{1}^{x} s^{1/s}\;ds,\qquad x>0
$$
Then $F'(x) = x^{1/x}$ so $F$ is an antiderivative.  There is no simpler way to write this.

Comment: So, x^(1/x) is the anti-derivitive of x^(1/x)?

Comment: No that function $F$ is the antiderivative of $x^{1/x}$.

Comment: Ok, thanks! This is very helpful!